# fs.watch unexpected behavior

Tags: node.js

If I run the below program as `node watcher.js file.txt`, then it works as expected when I touch `file.txt`. But if I open `file.txt` in vim and save, then it ceases to detect future modifications to the file. This seems really weird to me, why does this behavior occur?

```
var fs = require('fs');

var args = process.argv;
if (args.length <= 2) {
    console.log('USAGE: ' + args[1] + ' filename');
    process.exit(1);
}

var filename = args[2];

fs.watch(filename, function(event, filename) {
   console.log('file ' + filename + ' changed!');
});
```

Comment: are events continuing to log, you might need to log the event as well to the console, after the future modifications?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to inspect the content of the first argument, not just the filename. The issue is that `event` can be either `'change'` OR `'rename'`.

In this case, it looks like `vim` is actually renaming the old file and making a new one.